# Как Можно перегрузить Оператор ==, если необходимо проверить указатель на nullptr

Tags: c++, windows, ооп, указатели

Допустим в Классе есть указатель, тогда каким образом можно его проверить на nullptr. При попытке использовать простой if( a == nullptr) выдаёт ошибку C2678.

error C2678: бинарный "==": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "plane_metric::plane" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Я пытаюсь сделать это:

```
if (this->frame[index] == nullptr) {
    this->empty_index--;
    this->busy_index++;
}
return this->frame[index];
```

frame - Это массив типа plane< Field> В Классе dynamic_frame;
Field - Это Шаблон;

Comment: Так сравнивайте указатель с nullptr, а не объект класса. А если и перегружать, то `explicit operator bool` и `operator !` по аналогии с `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: как напоминание: каждый обьект имеет неявно указатель  this. Не нужно повсюду и постоянно указывать явно   this->a; this->b; this->c и т.д. Если вам нравится печатать или читать его каждый раз, то многим не понравится это читать постоянно....

Comment: Ты уверен что frame[index] это ptr? Проверь на null

Comment: Что вы называете "указателем" в данном случае? Компилятор же ясно сказал вам, что `this->frame[index]` - это `plane`, а не указатель. Вы хотите, чтобы в вашем случае `plane` выступал в роли некоего "обобщённого" указателя? Или что-то другое?

Comment: Прочитай про операции и орерандов, думаю тебе перегрузка не поможет.

Answer (score 3):

Навскидку пачка решений...

```
class Pointer1
{
public:
    void* ptr = nullptr;
};

class Pointer2
{
public:
    void* getptr() const { return ptr; }
private:
    void* ptr = nullptr;
};

class Pointer3
{
public:
    operator const void*() const { return ptr; }
private:
    void* ptr = nullptr;
};

class Pointer4
{
public:
    bool operator ==(const void * p) const { return ptr == p; }
private:
    void* ptr = nullptr;
};

class Pointer5
{
public:
    bool is_null() const { return ptr == nullptr; }
private:
    void* ptr = nullptr;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Pointer1 p1;
    if (p1.ptr == nullptr)       { cout << "p1 nullptr\n"; }
    Pointer2 p2;
    if (p2.getptr() == nullptr)  { cout << "p2 nullptr\n"; }
    Pointer3 p3;
    if (p3 == nullptr)           { cout << "p3 nullptr\n"; }
    Pointer4 p4;
    if (p4 == nullptr)           { cout << "p4 nullptr\n"; }
    Pointer5 p5;
    if (p5.is_null())            { cout << "p5 nullptr\n"; }
}
```